# Copy paste headers from first workbook ONLY

Tags: excel, header, copy, paste

I am wondering if anyone can help me with a code. 
I am trying to copy and paste the headers of the first workbook only (which have multiple sheets, all same headers/format in all the workbooks but different data). The Workbooks are in a loop. I can't figure out how to copy the headers from the first workbook in the loop only. If anyone can help me that would be great! Much appreciated!

I have the following code here here:

```
Sub simpleXLSMerger()
'Just change directory path and run code. Make sure workbook is not in the same direct as files to be merge
'Remember to add the same number of worksheets same as merge files
'If code does not work, or paste blanks into worksheet, try inserting code into a new module
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

DirectoryPath = InputBox("Directory Path")

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    'change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder(DirectoryPath)
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
    'Change number to the source sheet number you want to import (starts with 1)
    Worksheets(i).Activate

    Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    'Change number to the destination sheet number you want to import to (starts with 1)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    bookList.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next
Next i

MsgBox "DONE! =)"

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Sheets.Index = 1 Then Sheets(1).Range("A1:F1").Copy // ...`?

Comment: @BruceWayne umm I think that only copies the first sheet right? I am trying to copy all the headers (in multiple sheets) of the first workbook only (multiple workbooks)...

Comment: Then loop through the sheets of that first workbook? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, there are multiple workbooks with multiple sheets (all same format). I am trying to merge the workbooks together (which I can with the code above), but I need to tweak the code so that I am copying the headers once only.

Comment: Okay.  However you determine what the "first workbook" is, take that, loop through the sheets and get the headers. You could put them all in an array, or even dictionary (sheet name could be the key I guess) and go from there. What have you tried?